# Отправка PIL.Image картинки как документа через pyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, pil

Есть код, который должен отправить пользоветлю картинку, а затем её файл в формате PNG используя библиотек pyTelegramBotApi

```py
def get_bio_from_image(image: Image):
     ''' Returns bytes of the image     '''
     bio = BytesIO()
     bio.name = 'image.png'
     image.save(bio, 'PNG')
     bio.seek(0)
     return bio

...
...
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def main(message: telebot.types.Message):
     '''
     Handle the picture and then asking to continue
     :param message: Telegram message
     '''

     photo_id = message.photo[-1].file_id

     photo_file = bot.get_file(photo_id)
     photo_bytes = bot.download_file(photo_file.file_path)

     # Получает оригинальную картинку PIL.Image
     image = get_image_from_bytes(photo_bytes)

     # Получает отредактированную картинку типа PIL.Image
     new image = get_new_image(image) 

     # Возвращяет BytesIO от новой картинки
     bio_new_image = get_bio_from_image(new_image)

     # Отправляет new_image как фото при помощи BytesIO, всё отлично работает, картинка отображается
     bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=bio_new_image, caption='New image:')

     # Уже не получается отправить тк send_document  требует именно ФАЙЛ и
     # при отправке таким образом картинка отправится, но будет повреждённая
     bot.send_document(message.chat.id, data=bio_new_image, caption='Doc:')
```

Вариант с сохранением картинки не хочется использовать ( не сохранять же каждую созданную картинку по id пользователя на диске с дальнейшим удалением).
Как отправить изображение не сохраняя его на диске?
( если это возможно, если нет - что можно сделать с этим кодом чтобы выполнить цель даже с сохранением на диск)